# Aspect Around Transactional service throw UnexpectedRollbackException

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I Have Aspect around Methods in Transactional service. 
Unfortunately, when I catch  errors by service, another exception is throwed.  How can I prevent from this error ?
*I searched for similar question but no-one solutions seems be adequat for my case

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class ServiceGuard {   
    @Pointcut("execution(* simgenealogy.service.*.*(..))")
    public void persistence() {}

    @Around("persistence()")
    public Object logPersistence(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) { 
        try {
            Object o =  joinPoint.proceed();
            return o;
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException constraintException) {
            // (...)
            return null;
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            // (...)
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And error log.

```
2019-07-29 02:10:37.979 ERROR 11300 --- [ion Thread] s.a.g.s.w.ServiceGuard                   :
            Constraint violation: First Name cannot be empty
2019-07-29 02:10:38.023 ERROR 11300 --- [ion Thread] s.a.g.s.w.ServiceGuard                   :
            Constraint violation: Last Name cannot by empty
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:534)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:305)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found solution. 
 @Transactional is also @Arround Aspect.  The problem was in ordering aspects. My Guard class wasn't in fact around Transaction.  Put @Order(0) on Guard and @Order(1) on @Transactional service solved issue.

Answer (score 0):

You catch exceptions which probably occur for a reason. Then you just return null as the result of the previously executed (via `proceed()`) method, probably in situations where another, non-null return value is expected.

As you do not provide any application code, this is speculative, but I assume that the null return value is then assigned to a data property which ought have a non-null value (see the constraint violations in your log). More precisely you set first and last names to null which causes constraint violations which in turn causes your transaction to be rolled back because mandatory data fields are not set.

How to fix this? Either return non-null default values for first/last name (sounds strange, though) or let the original exceptions escalate instead of swallowing them and causing follow-up problems.

Bottom line: Your exception handling is just broken and needs fixing.

Comment: I return null because I would like to pass this value into Facade Layer if any error occure. This is correct return value. Constraint Error are ok in my test case. The third error is not ok.  If I  move my aspect to facade layer, all is fine.

Comment: Your answer surprises me, but be it as it may, in this case I request an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub reproducing the problem. An aspect without application it weaves into, a log with errors that are no error are definitely not enough for me to be able to help you.